# Display SQL message in visual basic app

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Hey so i have this trigger:

```html
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[atbl_Sales_OrdersLines_ITrigGG]
    ON [dbo].[atbl_Sales_OrdersLines]
    FOR INSERT
    AS 
    BEGIN
        IF (exists (select 1 from (
            select x.ProductId, totalOrdersQty, ISNULL(asp.Quantity, 0) PossibleQty from (
                select i.ProductId, sum(aso.Amount) totalOrdersQty 
                from (select distinct ProductId from inserted) i
                join atbl_Sales_OrdersLines aso on aso.ProductId = i.ProductId
                group by i.ProductId) x
            left join atbl_Sales_ProductS asp on asp.ProductId = x.ProductId
            ) x
            where PossibleQty < totalOrdersQty)) 
  BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Quantity is not sufficient' ,10,1)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
    END
```

Trigger works. When i try to do insert - it displays error message in SQL Server Manager. However, in visual basic app i also get error, but the message is not displayed in the popup.

Another thing, any ideas of how i could display the name of the product in that message (that lacks quantity).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to capture the SQL Error inner exception in Visual Basic and display it in your popup.

To display the name of the product, you can use the subquery that is in your `SELECT 1 FROM (...` query, and add the ProductName to the select list to populate a variable, and then use the variable in your RAISERROR string.  You'll need to decide what you want to do though, if there is more than one product that lacks quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encapsulate the execution of the insert in your APP within the `try...catch` structure and you will be able to show the message

Comment: thing is, insert is done by data grid, i do not know how to catch that :)